# Faking time without changing Windows system clock

Tags: datetime, testing, timezone, virtualization, clock

Does anybody know of a Windows tool to report fake dates/times to a process?

Apparently there are Linux programs that can be used to test how the software will react in the future / in a different timezone or to trigger scheduled tasks without actually modifying the system clock. Are there such programs for Windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[RunAsDate](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html) can do this.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Though it doesn't seem to affect the grand-child processes that the initial process might start, it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Starting about 2 years ago, I always abstract the call to DateTime.Now (C#) through a Utility class. This way I can always fake the date/time if I want to, or just pass it directly through to DateTime.Now.

Sounds similiar to what BillH suggested.

```
public class MyUtil
{
  public static DateTime GetDateTime()
  {
     return DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
     //return DateTime.Now;   
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean for this project, right? It wouldn't work system-wide, right? :-)

Comment: Correct. Only for a single project. Would be nice if the system gave you a way to abstract this away (at a system level). Can Docker do this? Use a false / incorrect time from the underlying system? I know a Virtual Machine could.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper your calls to the 'getCurrentDateTime()' system calls so you can introduce offsets or multipliers into the times your code reads during testing?